# Hosted message queue for Java-based app in AWS us-east?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, message-queue, publish-subscribe, paas

I'm looking for a **message queue as a service** that ..

- .. is hosted in AWS us-east
- .. offers real PubSub (not polling!)
- .. can be used in production
- .. offers high availability
- .. has a good client for Java

I only found [CloudAMQP](http://www.cloudamqp.com/) (still in beta), [AppEngine Task Queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview) (not AWS), SQS (polling only), [Redis To Go](http://redistogo.com/) (no high availability? -twitter stream seems full of issues) and [IronMQ](http://www.iron.io/products/mq) (polling only).

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Stephanos, why can't you do polling?

Comment: Well it's not like I can't, but for most non-pubsub message services (e.g. AWS and IronMQ) I'd be paying mostly for the polling since it counts as API calls. And that just seems unfair (+inefficient).

Comment: True, but it's pretty cheap. IronMQ for instance would be $2.34 per month if you polled every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [Iron.io](http://www.iron.io/) have added pub/sub. Maybe it fits your needs now? Also, it appears to talk beanstalkd, so you're potentially free to migrate easily to a self hosted solution at some point in the future (should you feel that urge!).

Comment: actually I'm using them already, totally forgot about this post - thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You should check one of the open PaaS available (Such as Cloudify, OpenShift or Cloudfoundry), using such PaaS one can easily on board most of the services and most of the popular message queues like - ActiveMQ, RabitMQ or SonicMQ.

[Cloudify](http://www.cloudifysource.org)  (Which I'm one of its contributor) is open source and free, can on board lamosy any message queue you want on any cloud.
You can easily on board ActiveMQ, RabitMQ, SonicMQ or another service you used to work with off the cloud.

Comment: thanks for the info! -but I need something 'managed/hosted' for me

Comment: you should consider the fact that using a hosted service will leave you locked to this vendor and with a unique management tool.
What about the rest of your application? How are you going to manage it?

Comment: I run on Heroku, database is on MongoHQ. I don't want to handle servers, I want to write code. I don't think I'm really locked-in since Redis/AMQP are 'standardized' and I could just switch to another vendor/do it myself. It's not like a database where you would have to do data migrations, it's just a message queue...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pure messaging solutions?  http://www.pubnub.com/faq  or http://pusher.com ? According to their websites they have presence on EC2.

Comment: I considered it. But the PubNub support told me there would be a few problems (discarding 'old' messages, 24-hour reset) for this use case. And Pusher seems WebSockets only.